# Making a RSS feed clickable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rss

I have not been programming for long and I am stuck on a RSS feed problem, I have programmed a rss feed into my application and I cannot get the url to pass to the browser to open I keep getting errors on the geturl and get intent lines all I want this code to do is geturl and open the link in a webview here is what I have so far;

This is my RssActivity code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    List<JSONObject> jobs = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    try {
        jobs = RssReader.getLatestRssFeed();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error loading RSS Feed Stream >> " + e.getMessage() + " //" + e.toString());
    }

    adapter = new RssListAdapter(this,jobs);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {



     if (position == 2) {
         adapter.getItem(position).getUrl().toString();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Webb.class);

               startActivity(intent);}
}}
```

This is my Webview;

public class Webb extends Activity { 
    private ProgressDialog progressBar;
    public WebView webview;
    private static final String TAG = "Main";

```
@Override 
public void onStart()
{
super.onStart();
CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();

}




public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();

extras (Intent.putExtra("url", Url));

setContentView(R.layout.browser1);

CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);

CookieSyncManager.getInstance().startSync();

webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

webview.loadUrl(getIntent.getStringExtra("url"));

webview.setWebViewClient(new testClient());

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a RSS feed clickable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087470/making-a-rss-feed-clickable)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you display your rss feeds

If you display them in ListView - override

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {}
```

method in your list activity

If there is a button in your layout.xml - set the button OnClickListener

```
    sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // your code there
        }
    });
```

To open url in WebView use loadUrl method

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.page_content);
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: Hi Sid,here is a link to the tutorial I used where would I place everything  http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-rss-reader-tutorial.html

Comment: add onListItemClick method in RssActivity class. Use adapter.getItem(position).getUrl().toString() to get the url string. Then start your activity with browser, put the url in extras (itent.putExtra("url", url)). And in onCreate method of your browser activity use webView.loadUrl(getIntent.getStringExtra("url"))

Comment: I get this error on the onclick method; The method getUrl is undefined for the type JSONObject, I also get this error in the webview activity

Comment: read about JSONObject - http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html. I don't have your code, but i guess, you shoukd use something like getString("url") to get the url

Answer (score 0):

First, you did not say what kind of error you get. This could be extremely helpful.
Second, I am not an Android specialist at all but I reviewed your code and saw that you use method getIntent() one time and the second time you are using variable `getIntent`:

`webview.loadUrl(getIntent.getStringExtra("url"));`

Unfortunately I do not see definition of this variable.

Due to you did not explain the details of error you get I assumed that probably it is a compilation error because you try to use variable that does not exist. Is my assumption reasonable?

Comment: Yes I believe your assumption is correct, it says the method geturl is undefined for the type JSONObject, I was advised this was how it was done so I assumed I had just put things in the wrong order, I am using this rss reader; http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.com/2010/08/android-rss-reader-tutorial.html